# How to say I have played the main story of a game?

Tags: collocation

I just played a game from the start to the end of main story, there are many other challenges in the game left untouched, so I think I can't say 'game completed', can I?

I know the following possible candidates

'completed'
'ended'
'walked through'
'cleared'(well, in Japan they use this word)

But I'm not satisfied with these ones, what is(are) the right word(s) to describe that I have seen the outro of a game? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it depends on the game.  When I played Diablo II, I would say I just beat the game on normal mode with (paladin/ barbarian/ amazon/ necromancer/ sorceress).

Comment: Thanks! Now I see many mistakes in Japanes-English. They say 'clear' Diablo, and 'complete' if all the side missions are done, all the treasures are collected, etc.

Comment: You might also want to say "played through the story", or "completed a playthrough", as many games (like borderlands) talk about "playthrough 2" or "second playthrough" with a higher difficulty level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the 80's we used to say 'clocked', as in *'I **clocked** Boulder Dash'*. You finished the last level, beat the final boss, got the credits screen. It comes from games where the points clock would literally roll over and start counting from e.g. -32768.

I think you can say *completed* for sure, and *clocked* too, because you've finished the main storyline, you've seen the credits roll.

To finish off all the side missions, that would maybe be *exhausted*. There's no game content left; *I've exhausted it*.

Comment: If I can say 'complete' then I'd like to say so, because it's easy for me. Many thanks! By the way, I just completed Batman Arkham City ^ ^

Answer (score 0):

**You beat it but you've yet to complete it.**

For example, you aren't 'done' with *Castlevania Symphony of the Night* until you've reached [200.6% completion](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/60833/how-do-i-get-200-6-map-completion) and even if you only defeat Richter (prematurely rolling the end credits whilst content remains), you've still *beat* the game, having been treated to one of the game's possible endings.

Really it depends, if I have to ask what ending did you get? Generally with games that have multiple endings, you're expected to have specified it. Likewise if you wish to convey that you did actually "100% complete it". Otherwise I'd assume you just beat the game.

Plain, vanilla, beat it. No side quests. Just plot stuff. Might as well have been a [speedrun](https://www.google.com/search?q=richter%20speed%20run&oq=richter%20speed%20run&aqs=chrome..69i57.38227j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: Many thanks! I didn't realize actually there are different kinds of endings for some games as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I simply state I finished the quest line.
If multiple endings are involved then it's "such n such" quest line. This tells people you have beaten the main storyline.

Comment: Many thanks! Now I see the word 'beat' several times in this thread, so I reckon it must be widely used in gaming.